# php popen traceroute doesn't always return

Tags: php, windows, popen, traceroute

I have to proceed to a lot of traceroutes as quickly as possible with PHP on Windows. Here's my code :

```
function tracert($addresses){
    set_time_limit(300);
    $nbAddresses=count($addresses);
    for($i=0; $i<$nbAddresses; $i++){
        $tracerts[$i]=popen('tracert '.$addresses[$i], 'r');
    }
    for($i=0; $i<$nbAddresses; $i++){
        $results[$i]="<strong>".($i+1).")</strong>";
        while(!feof($tracerts[$i])){
            $results[$i].=fgets($tracerts[$i])."<br/>";
        }
        fclose($tracerts[$i]);
    }
    return $results;
}
```

I'm looping twice : in the first loop I launch the traceroutes with popen(), and in the second loop I'm getting the results back in a table with fgets().

But sometimes, it doesn't work : the traceroute return is empty. So basicaly my program just displays the number of the traceroute and goes to the next. It happens approximatively once every four or five traceroutes.

How can I make it work everytime ?

Comment: Not sure, but is it exceeding maximum execution time?

Comment: No, with 20 traceroutes, the program ends in 1:45, and I set the time limit to 5:00, but 4 or 5 of the traceroutes are empty, mostly around the end.